SSIS OLE DB Command Calling Oracle Stored Procedure - How to capture Ouput Parameter
In Visual Studio 2022, I'm using an OLE DB Command to call a Stored Procedure.
If my stored procedure just has Input parameters, it works fine - I can pass the parameters with the '?' syntax (eg BenWalkerTestProc.OneInParameter(?);) and it works fine.
However, I need to add Out parameters in my Stored Pocedure and deal with the results.
I've ready lots of different posts and articles but I've not been able to get anything working.
For example, none of the guidance here works: Call Oracle stored proc with output parameter but this is from 2012.
I've tried adding another ? but then I'm told my parameters aren't bound. I can't manually add another parameter in the Input and Output properties.
I've tried using EXEC.
I've tried using the OUT and OUTPUT keywords.
Does anyone know how to do this? I've read so many posts and tried so many different ways.

I've tried this:
declare
v_rtn_code integer;
begin
BenWalkerTestProc.OneInParameterOneOutParameter(I_LANGUAGE => ?, O_RTN_CODE=>v_rtn_code);
?:=v_rtn_code;
end;
and this:
declare
v_rtn_code integer;
myStatement varchar2(500);
begin
myStatement:='exec BenWalkerTestProc.OneInParameterOneOutParameter(:1,:2);
execute immediate myStatement using output v_rtn_code;
end;
and this:
EXEC BenWalkerTestProc.OneInParameterOneOutParameter (?.?)
and this:
EXEC BenWalkerTestProc.OneInParameterOneOutParameter (?)
and lots of other things
